# How to differentiate between a bound callable member reference and a function of the same type in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, jvm, kotlin

When it comes to a method signature or definition, is there any way to differentiate

```
users().indexOn(User::id)
```

and

```
users().indexOn<User, String> { it.id() }
```

? That is, to specify that a bound member reference is required and not a function instance, or vice versa. Here is the signature of the above example:

```
fun <T: SomeType, U> indexOn(function: (T) -> U): List<U>
```

On the same note, is it possible to differentiate between a constructor reference and a function which just returns a type? E.g. `query(::SomeLookup)` vs. `query { SomeLookup(args) }` (without kotlin.reflect, if possible)

Comment: But why? What it the point?

Comment: @Kevinrob curiosity. Function reflection is coming, after all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to distinguish a lambda from a function reference within the type system is using the reflection interface `KFunction<T>`, for example:

```
fun <T> f(ref: T) where T : () -> Unit, T : KFunction<Unit> { /* ... */ }
```

```
fun g() { println("hello") }
f(::g) // OK

f { println("hello") } // Error: type parameter bound is not satisfied
```

Though I could not make it work the other way around for now.

Also, I found no way to distinguish a constructor reference by its type. At runtime, however, it is easy to do that through reflection: you can check whether a `javaConstructor` of a `KFunction<*>` is null.

Comment: didn't know about the `where` keyword until now. Double checked the reference page and found a small paragraph on it at the bottom, really useful though, thanks!

Comment: I may be missing something but your example doesn't need generics at all, correct? e.g. `fun f(ref: KFunction<Unit>): Unit`

Comment: Furthermore, if you want to be able to accept `KProperty` in addition to `KFunction` for value returning callables then `KCallable` can be used: `fun <R> f(ref: KCallable<R>): R`